# Nyx ~/.nyx/cache.sqlite permissions error

Tags: nyx

I'm repeatedly getting an error from nyx running under Ubuntu 18.04.  It's fine on first run after a reboot.  After a while, the terminal it's in shows a chaotic and frozen pattern.  Quitting out and restarting, produces the error below, which ends in:

`sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database`

The problem appears to be ~/.nyx/cache.sqlite, which is owned by root and which nyx is trying to write on startup/shutdown.  I tried changing permissions from 644 to 664, and then even 666, but that didn't help.  On the other hand, changing ownership to myself did help.  Is this a security risk?  Why didn't 666, which should have given everyone write permission, work?

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/nyx", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nyx==2.0.4', 'console_scripts', 'nyx')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/__init__.py", line 176, in main
    nyx.starter.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stem/util/conf.py", line 289, in wrapped
    return func(*args, config = config, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/starter.py", line 118, in main
    nyx.curses.start(nyx.draw_loop, acs_support = config.get('acs_support', True), transparent_background = True, cursor = False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/curses.py", line 217, in start
    curses.wrapper(_wrapper)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/curses.py", line 215, in _wrapper
    function()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/__init__.py", line 194, in draw_loop
    interface = nyx_interface()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/__init__.py", line 256, in nyx_interface
    Interface()  # constructor sets NYX_INTERFACE
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/__init__.py", line 589, in __init__
    self._header_panel = nyx.panel.header.HeaderPanel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/panel/header.py", line 47, in __init__
    self._vals = Sampling.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/panel/header.py", line 235, in create
    my_router_status_entry = nyx.tracker.get_consensus_tracker().my_router_status_entry()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/tracker.py", line 169, in get_consensus_tracker
    CONSENSUS_TRACKER = ConsensusTracker()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/tracker.py", line 831, in __init__
    self._update(ns_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/tracker.py", line 853, in _update
    writer.record_relay(fingerprint, address, or_port, nickname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/__init__.py", line 569, in record_relay
    self._cache._query('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO relays(fingerprint, address, or_port, nickname) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', fingerprint, address, or_port, nickname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/__init__.py", line 541, in _query
    return self._conn.execute(query, param)
sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which [has been reported](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/27938).

I do not know if my work-around was a security risk, but the solution that they offer on the bug tracker is:

`Users should be able to work around this with the following...
% echo "data_directory disabled" >> my_nyxrc
% nyx --config my_nyxrc`

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Changing the owner of the config directory to the current user and group fixed the error for me:
`sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) -R ~/.nyx`

Explanation:
On the first run (on Ubuntu 18.04) I started `nyx` logged in as a regular user with `sudo nyx`. A notice was shown: `Nyx is currently running with root permissions. This isn't a good idea, nor should it be necessary`. While `nyx` ran normally, it created its config directory `~/.nyx` (containing the SQLite database) owned by `root:root`.
Later, I started `nyx` again as a regular user and it crashed with the error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database`.